# XML error - Doing Google Android NDK Lesson 1

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-ndk

The Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The error message:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\My First App\res\layout\activity_main.xml:7: Unexpected element "{}LinearLayout" {antlib:org.apache.tools.ant}LinearLayout
```

The code is almost exactly the same as the code on the Android website and it's really frustrating that I can't seem to get it to work. Is the problem in the code, or is it on my side? I am using Eclipse

Comment: You say almost the same.  How is it different?

Comment: just this the id/bsend part. the code on google's website is this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Comment: Probably related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581251/how-do-i-fix-unexpected-element-target-antliborg-apache-tools-anttarget

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error. I was using Indigo in Ubuntu 12.04, and no matter what libraries I got or eclipse plugins I used it was always there.

What worked for me was re-downloading and reinstalling the Android SDK (probably not necessary in your case), and downloading Eclipse Classic (Juno) from the Eclipse website rather than using the Indigo package that was in the repos. The lesson said Classic was recommended anyway, so whatever, I'm just happy it works now.

If you are using Windows, I'd still suggest downloading the most recent Classic version, but otherwise I can't be of help there.